# Boot to CLI vs GUI terminal: What's the difference?

Tags: raspbian, gui, terminal

I recently realized that I don't use any of the features of the GUI of raspbian other than the terminal for my current project. I therefore decided that, rather than boot in to the GUI desktop only to click on the terminal, full-screen it, then un-decorate it, I could speed things up by just booting directly into the CLI (by setting the boot/log-in setting via `raspi-config`).

This, of course, boots directly into the CLI; however, the display is clearly different. The colors and font are different.

My question is, how does the 'boot CLI/terminal' differ from the one that is loaded in the GUI desktop? and, also, how can I make the boot CLI look the same as the GUI one (same colours/font etc)?

Comment: your question belongs at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-GUI interface is called a *virtual console* (VC) or *[virtual terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console)* (VT) and it runs on a virtual device called a TTY; see:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con

There are actually 6 of them instantiated at boot and you can cycle through them with Alt-Ctrl-F[1-6] (this works from the GUI desktop too, which occupies one of the VCs when running). There are historical and wide ranging hardware/software compatibility reasons for this interface stack, and it is not unique to linux (although the specific implementation is referred to as "the linux console").

A GUI CLI interface is called a *terminal emulator*<sup>1</sup> and there are a variety of them, I believe the default on Rpi OS is [the LXTerminal](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTerminal), part of the LXDE environment the RpiOS GUI is derived from. You will often see these referred to as "virtual terminals" by people who don't know/understand/care about the difference.

> how can I make the boot CLI look the same as the GUI one (same colours/font etc)

You probably can't exactly, although you may be able to come close.  Although in theory the non-GUI console supports 24-bit color (as the GUI consoles do), there isn't a lot of application for it (and some of the libraries in Raspbian are compiled for only 8 or 256 color).  The fonts are also more limited; you can set that via `setupcon` (see `man setupcon`), although this may (or may not, I don't know) get overriden by `systemd` at boot; that font is set in `/etc/vconsole.conf` where you can set `FONT` to the basename of a file from `/usr/share/consolefonts` (eg. for `Uni1-VGA32x16.psf.gz` use `Uni1-VGA32x16`).  You may find some fonts to install with `apt search font | grep -iB 1 console` although I think most of them are there already.

---

1. Might be more accurate to say a terminal emulator provides a text console interface in accord with some specific standards, and the shell provides the CLI proper.  Really this is true of the virtual consoles too.